# How do I activate services in slack for Mac?

Tags: macos, automator, slack

When I use Slack's desktop app on mac I do not get the expected services contextual menu when I right-click. I just get 2 options, 'copy' and 'search with google'. I am specifically wanting to display the 'reveal in finder' service that is available in every other app that I am aware of. They keyboard shortcut for this service also does not work.

I use this a lot to follow local file paths on our server that our team share with each other.

I am aware that it is possible to do this by copying the path, going to finder opening 'Go to' and pasting the file path in but this is a slow process. (and in every other app an unnecessary process)

I cannot get Automator to create a service for slack that actually works.

Answer (score 3):

Slack is not a truly native UI for the Mac. It's a web view that has a couple of integration points into Mac OS, but that web view doesn't allow it access to system services.

Update:

I found that adding a system-wide shortcut for the service that you are interested in will allow you to access that service item from Slack. For example, I have an automator script that opens up JIRA keys in Safari and from Slack I simply highlight the key and use ⇧⌘O to activate the automator script.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? What do you mean "adding a system-wide shortcut"?

Comment: @PatrickHennessey - here's an explanation and instructions on how to do it. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167967/creating-system-wide-keyboard-shortcut-to-launch-applications

Comment: Wow! I didn't know you could add shortcuts for automator services like this! Huge help. Thanks